# How to make a dict that returns colors for a continuos color palette?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a vector of values that goes from 0 to 1 and need to create a dict that, when provided any number between those values, will return the appropriate color in a continues color palette, black been zero (#000000) and 1 being red (#FF0000). I can create a continues color pallette with seaborn, like shown below, but the 'ListedColormap' object is not iterable, which means I cannot turn it into a dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, z = np.random.rand(3, 100)
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
points = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, cmap=cmap)
f.colorbar(points)
```

Is there a way to turn 'ListedColormap' object into an iterable object, or a different way to create a dictionary long enough to resemble a continuos color palette?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colormap as a function:

```
color = cmap(value)
```

This will perform the same task as the dictionary.

If you must have a dictionary, build one using `cmap()`:

```
cmap_as_a_dict = {x: cmap(x) for x in np.linspace(0., 1., 100)}
```

Note that this will interpolate the points obtained from `sns.cubehelix_palette`. It is more accurate to ask for more levels:

```
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(n_colors=100, as_cmap=True)
```